# PHP/Codeigniter compare object(stdClass) and string array with array_intersect

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

i'm kind of new to PHP and Codeigniter.

I'm trying to compare 2 different arrays (one with strings and one with object(stdClass), and count the similar values of them, to calculate a result. Is there any possibility to solve this, like converting the objects to strings or vice versa? Any help will be appreciated.

This is some of the code i have right now:

Result.php

```
$countcorrectuser = count(array_intersect($_SESSION['correctanswers'], $_SESSION['useranswers']));
$countcorrect = count($_SESSION['correctanswers']);
$totalresult = $countcorrectuser / $countcorrect;
$this->session->set_userdata('totalresult', $totalresult);
```

Run.php

```
// $_SESSION['correctanswers']
$correctanswers = $this->Question_model->getAllAnswers();
$this->session->set_userdata('correctanswers', $correctanswers);

// $_SESSION['useranswers'] When the next question submit button is pressed
if(!isset($_SESSION['useranswers'])){
    $_SESSION['useranswers'] = array();
}
    $_SESSION['useranswers'][] = $this->input->post('useranswer');
```

Question_model.php

```
function getAllAnswers(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT answer FROM question WHERE exam_id = \'' . $_SESSION['examid'] .'\'');
    return $query->result();
}
```

Example of var_dump($_SESSION['correctanswers']);

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["answer"]=> string(6) "answer" } etc.
```

Example of var_dump($_SESSION['usersanswers']);

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "answer" etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes from your code are for the sake of readability. It also uses [Query Binding](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) for readability and security.

The query results use a  `foreach` loop to create an array that matches the `$_SESSION['usersanswers']` structure.

```
function getAllAnswers()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT answer FROM question WHERE exam_id = ?';
    $answers = $this->db->query($sql, [$_SESSION['examid']])->result();
    $results = [];//empty array so there is always something to return
    foreach($answers as $answer){
        $results[] = $answer->answer;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The objects are arrays now, like arrays in a array. Like this: array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["answer"]=> string(6) "answer" } etc. Is there a way to convert the arrays in the array to just strings in a array? I'm getting this error: Message: Array to string conversion

Comment: Checkout my revised answer.